# Create a summary data table in r

Tags: r

I have a data frame in R with the following sample data:

```
choice  Wealth
1       10
2       5
3       8
3       10
2       10
3       5
1       8
2       5
2       5
```

I am trying to create a summary table that shows the %choice by wealth level (i.e. of those with wealth x, how many chose 1 or 2 or 3):

```
Wealth %choice1 %choice2 %choice3
5      0%       75%      25%
8      50%      0%       50%
10     33%      33%      33%
```

I've tried a number of different methods but can't seem to get this correct (table, dplyr, etc.). As I am a novice in R, any ideas or help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check with `rowSums` with `table`

```
tb=table(df$Wealth,df$choice)
tb/rowSums(tb)

           1         2         3
5  0.0000000 0.7500000 0.2500000
8  0.5000000 0.0000000 0.5000000
10 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.3333333
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way with the `tabyl` function from the `janitor` package:

```
library(janitor); library(dplyr)
df %>%
  tabyl(Wealth, choice) %>%
  adorn_percentages("row")

# Wealth         1         2         3
#      5 0.0000000 0.7500000 0.2500000
#      8 0.5000000 0.0000000 0.5000000
#     10 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.3333333
```